# Apply regex to a dynamic Rails link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, gsub

Is it possible to apply a regex solution a Rails link?

For example, I have this link:

```
venue_news_index_path(sensitive_venue)
```

Which yields this:

```
/leisure/venuename/news
```

I want to apply this:

```
^(.*)(\/.*)$
```

and then `gsub`:

```
$1#$2
```

to achieve this:

```
/leisure/venuename#/news
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call a `_path` or `_url` method, all it does is return a string, so you can `gsub` that result as you need to.

Note that Rails will treat that as going to `/leisure/venuename` in any link/form/or redirect due to the `#` being a location on a particular page, not a unique URL.

**Edit**

Managed to get a stricter regex working. Problem with `.*` is it gets slashes and such too.

```
 path.gsub(/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]*$/) do |match|
   "##{match}"
 end
```